# Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.GetManifest() failed status

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've trying to process a file that uploads+renders fine on the demo autodesk viewer (i.e. viewer.autodesk.com).  The GetManifest result has a progress of "complete" but a status of "failed".  If I dump the contents of the GetManifest() call I get the following which has Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829 in the message.  Wondering why it completes and renders on the online Autodesk viewer.  The translation completes w\ "success", but when I try and get the manifest (so that I can download the derivatives), it fails on the GetManifest() call.

? manifest.ToString()
"{
\r\n  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a2FodWFtb2RlbHMvOWNjNjA2Njg2NGIwNDViNDg5NjhhNDMxNjI1NmEzNTMuSUZD",
\r\n  "derivatives": [
\r\n    {
\r\n      "hasThumbnail": "false",\r\n      "name": "LMV Bubble",\r\n      "progress": "complete",\r\n      "messages": [
\r\n        {\r\n          "type": "error",
\r\n          "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829",
\r\n          "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n
"outputType": "svf",\r\n      "status": "failed"\r\n    }\r\n  ],
\r\n  "hasThumbnail": "false",\r\n  "progress": "complete",\r\n  "type": "manifest",\r\n  "region": "US",\r\n  "version": "1.0",\r\n  "status": "failed"\r\n}"

Comment: The file can be accessed here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VwC_acdo8b7IPyyx24dxcRAtrfi_LASo/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this IFC model is IFC4, please use the modern conversion method instead.

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-ads-force: true' \
--data'{
   "input": {
     "urn": "{URN}"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "3d"
         ],
         "advanced": {
            "conversionMethod": "modern"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

Comment: Can this option just be set for all IFC files?  Not sure how I could determine when it would be appropriate to set this option.

Comment: Currently, the `conversionMethod` is only applied to IFC files, and the modern IFC conversion method is the recommended one. The legacy won't get updates as I know. However, it's a good practice that you set this option to the IFC file in case of any changes have been made in the future.